# How to add "NAV packets" to a video file?

Tags: video

I am using Ubuntu 10.04, and I want to add a video file to Bombono DVD 0.5.5 - but it complains the file does not contain "NAV packets". The file was obtained by dvdrip, from a DVD (no transcoding - it is the actual VOB file in the temp folder).

My question is: **how do I add these NAV packets to the video file**, so the DVD authoring program Bombono can accept it?

Bombono's error message also says:

`Bombono DVD can use "DVD-ready" video only now. Use muxing programs like "mplex -f 8" (from mjpegtools), mencoder (from mplayer) or transcode to make your video ready for Bombono DVD.`

So, I have tried `mplex -f 8 -o output.vob input.vob`, but it returns:

`**ERROR: [mplex] File input.vob unrecogniseable!`

I don't know how the `mencoder` command could be used for the purpose... anyone can help me?

NOTE: upgrading Bombono is **not** an option

Answer (score 4):

After some research and testing, I have reached the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.vob -f vob -target ntsc-dvd -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.vob
```

It is working fine! It does minimal processing (if it very fast), and the output is accepted by Bombono, i.e., the NAV packets are added!